# How to I regex match a list reference in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings from which I need to remove all elements that match a substring from another list. I am trying to do this with lists, nested loops, and regex.

The output from the following snippet produces ["We don't", "need no", "education"] instead of the desired ["education"]. I'm new to Python and this is my first experiment with regex, and I'm stuck on the sytax.

```
import re

testfile = ["We don't", "need no", "education"]
stopwords = ["We", "no"]
dellist = []

for x in range(len(testfile)):
    for y in range(len(stopwords)):
        if re.match(r'\b' + stopwords[y] + '\b', testfile[x], re.I):
            dellist.append(testfile[x])

for x in range(len(dellist)):
    if dellist[x] in testfile:
        del testfile[testfile.index(dellist[x])]

print testfile
```

The line

```
if re.match(r'\b' + stopwords[y] + '\b', testfile[x], re.I):
```

returns "None" for all iterations through the loop, so I'm guessing this is where my problem lies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `re.match` tests for a match from the *start* of the string.

Try `re.search` instead. Also, you're missing the `r` on your second `'\b'`:

```
if re.search(r'\b' + stopwords[y] + r'\b', testfile[x], re.I):
```

---

Also, you could just use list comprehension to build up `dellist` (you could probably use list comprehension to build up the new `testfile` entirely, but it escapes me at the moment):

```
dellist = [w for w in testfile for test in stopwords if re.search(test,w,re.I)]
```

---

Another thought - since you're using `re` module anyway, why don't you combine your `stopwords` into `\b(We|no)\b` and then you can just test `testfile` against the *one* regex?

```
regex = r'\b(' + '|'.join(stopwords) + r')\b'  # r'\b(We|no)\b'
```

Now you just have to look for words that *don't* match that regex:

```
newtestfile = [w for w in testfile if re.search(regex,w,re.I) is None]
# newtestfile is ['education']
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the basic `in` operator?  Should be considerably faster than the regex too.

```
for line in testfile:
    for word in stopwords:
        if word in line:
            do stuff
```

Or, how about a nifty [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) ;)

```
[line for line in testfile if not [word for word in stopwords if word in line]]
```

Comment: Breaks if the word is inside another 'innovate' would match against 'no', for example.

Comment: Excellent point.  We could compare against `' ' + word` and `word + ' '` or where the `len(word) == len(line)`.  Start eating into the performance gain, but it's probably still worth testing. Regex is usually pretty expensive especially when spinning over a large data set like this.

Comment: `not any(word in line for word in stopwords)` is more efficient that creating that temporary list

Comment: Yes, the complexity of the data set I'm working with rules out a pretty usage of in, unfortunately. I did follow your syntax for the loops however which made the code much cleaner. Will have to start learning about list comprehension, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

Prettier with `in` instead of regex's but the examples above would break if the stopword was contained within another word. This example only matches on complete words:

```
testfile = ["We don't", "need no", "education"]
stopwords = ["We", "no"]
output = []

for sentence in testfile:
    bad = false

    for word in sentence.split(' '):
        if word in stopwords:
            bad = true
            break

    if not bad:
        output.append(sentence)
```