# How to find an element in a list which is part of another element in another list in Python

Tags: python, list, find

I have this list:

```
dc = ["hello", "world"]
```

And this other:

```
lines = ["This is", "an example of hello", "line in the world of strings", "Testing"]
```

I wish to find those elements on dc which are part of any element of lines...

I may loop lines as:

```
for line in lines:
    # what to do here?
```

But I don't know how to find exactly that the "hello" element in dc is found in the "an example of hello" elemento of lines or that "world" in dc is found in the "line in the world of strings" in lines...

Maybe I shouldn't loop through lines?

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676821/how-to-i-regex-match-a-list-reference-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> dc = ["hello", "world", "foo"]
>>> lines = ["This is", "an example of hello", "line in the world of strings", "Testing"]
>>> [word for word in dc if any(word in line for line in lines)]
['hello', 'world']
```

Comment: Note that possible matches will occur on partial words.  The `in` operator is still a good choice imo, but the solution takes a bit more work.  Take a look at the discussion under a number of the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676821/how-to-i-regex-match-a-list-reference-in-python

Comment: @gfortune: The question doesn't mention words at all, so I don't understand what you mean. What solution to what problem do you have in mind?

Comment: in fact, for my particular case, lines won't have large words containing substrings from dc, unless as separate words, so this is the solution ;)

Comment: Sounds like you're set then.  Your example data looks suspiciously "word-like" :)

Comment: @JavierNovoaC.: In case you would like shorter solution, you could look at my answer ;) It uses set intersections, ideal for getting common elements of two iterables (in this case: two lists of words).

Answer (score 1):

### One liner solution using `set`'s features

First get all the words from the lines you have. Get them as a set for saving space and getting some useful features (see later). Then use `&` operation on the above and set created from the words you are looking for. The solution could be a one line:

```py
>>> set(dc) & set(sum(map(str.split, lines), []))
set(['world', 'hello'])
```

If you want the result as a list, just convert it to list like that:

```py
>>> list(set(dc) & set(sum(map(str.split, lines), [])))
['world', 'hello']
```

Comment: this will not work if you have dc=['hel lo'] and line=['hel lo example']

Comment: @Winston: Yup, this solution assumes OP wants to find words from `dc` that occur in any element of `lines`. Therefore my solution for `dc=['map', 'something']; line=['mapping is not something you are looking for']` will return `['something']` instead of `['map', 'something']`. Which is **huge advantage if you are looking for words, not substrings**.